# Android -Search in external sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, search

I'm trying to find a "description" of a "person" within a database stored in the sd. the row in the database are "_ID, name, description".

I created a "EditText" and a "button" where the name of the person is written and pressing the button will search the database required information. I also placed two TextView, one that says the name of the person, and in the other the description.
but I could not access the external database, is not whether to use DBHelper because the database is already created, (I can not create it again as many names and a big description).

Someone could help me with some tutorial or some explanation? ThankYou for Ur Helps Masters!.

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem with

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("path", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
```